# Adding a homepage field to package.json in react app not translating to build

Tags: reactjs, build

I'm trying to launch a React app (create-react-app) to GoDaddy using cPanel and I am having issues creating the correct build. I am setting the homepage in package.json underneath "name" and "version" (not sure if order matters here) like this:

`"homepage": "http://mydomainname.org"`

However, when I run *`npm run build`*, I get a message saying `"The project was built assuming it is hosted at /. You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.`

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: @Raymond Mutyaba I just gave that a shot and it's still giving me the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That message is not an error. After you run the `npm run build` command a folder named build should appear and it contains your react app. You need to upload the contents of that folder to the public_html folder in cpanel's file manager. (Make sure you are uploading what is inside the build folder and not the build folder itself). [Here is a link to a short tutorial](https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6)

Comment: I do all that and the website still does not load up?